# CyanogenMod for Samsung Galaxy S Advance. Which version?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-advance

Which version of CyanogenMod should I use for Samsung Galaxy S Advance and where should I download it from? I'm interested in CyanogenMod 11 but maybe there is a better choice? I wouldn't like to download wrong version so I'll be grateful for exact link. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Galaxy S Advance is not officially supported by CyanogenMod. They provide links to several unofficial ports on [their wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Unofficial_Ports#Samsung_Galaxy_S_Advance_.28GT-I9070.29), however:

- [CyanogenMod 10](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2248822)
- [CyanogenMod 10.1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2108362)
- [CyanogenMod 11](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2578599)

Since these are not officially provided by the CM team, they may not contain all of the features/changes in a supported build, and you would need to contact the developer of the build directly if you experience issues.